# How to compare a column with previous column when the new column has more data sets in it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to compare weekly account sales numbers to their previous weekly amount. However the new week has more accounts in it (on average 50 more) than the previous one, how can I add these accounts to the list without disrupting the previous data. I can't just add the new info to the bottom of the list because of sorting reason.

Comment: It seems like you have two questions, the first one being "How do I add new data (including entries not present in the current data) in a new column, and put the new column into sort order?" It seems that you're going to need to open up gaps in the existing column(s). Beyond that, what, exactly, are you asking? What do you mean by "compare"?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take a minute to read [ask] and improve your question by [edit]ing it to have more details of what you've done/tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: If you are comparing the weekly sales number, why is it important that you need to know what accounts make up each week? Can you provide some sample data (redacted if necessary) and perhaps a chart or another list of how you want the data to ideally appear. To start, if you code each week with a specific date, you can group those dates and add up the sales for each account into a pivot table. You can further create a pivot chart from that data.

Answer (score 0):

Add the new accounts to the bottom and use the excel sort functionality to re-sort the data by whichever criteria required. Using a pivot table table sounds like a great alternative; contingent upon whether your data is week-to-date, MTD, or YTD.